# Loading /api/locales is messing up the performance of the website (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, performance, cookies, next.js, localization

I am building a website in Next.js and I am facing the issue that when the page is initially loaded or the language is changed the text takes very long to load, so there are first empty containers and the text loads 1 or 2 seconds after it. I don't want to add a loading circle or let the containers wait for the text.
Instead I want to increase the speed of the text being loaded.

So the Client always has to ask the server when the language is changed.
Reason for it is that I build an API which loads the YML specific to the selected locale.
The reason for that is that I implemented a English and German version of the Website.
In the initial load I check if the user has already "en" or "de" stored in his cookies so that I know which YML I need and then call the API with that value which provides me with the right texts.

Like this:

**locale.js**

```
import path from 'path';

const fs = require('fs');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');

export default function handler(req, res) {
  const lang = req.query?.lang;
  const dirPath = path.join(process.cwd(), `locales/${lang.toLowerCase()}`);
  if (lang) {
    try {
      const dictionary = fs
        .readdirSync(dirPath)
        .map((fil) => yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(`${dirPath}/${fil}`, 'utf8')))
        .reduce((a, b) => {
          return { ...a, ...b };
        });
      res.status(200).json(dictionary);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json('Langauge not supported');
    }
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Missing Parameter: lang' });
  }
}
```

and then I have a useLocale() hook which accesses the API:

**useLocale.tsx**:

```
export default function useLocale() {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState('de');
  const [dictionary, setDictionary] = useState<MaybeEntry>({});
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isLocaleLoaded, setIsLocaleLoaded] = useState(false);

  const switchLocale = (lang: SupportedLanguage) => {
    axios({ method: 'GET', url: `/api/locale?lang=${lang}` })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data) {
          setDictionary(res.data);
          setLocale(lang);
          setCookie('locale', lang);
          const htmlElem = document.querySelector('html');
          if (htmlElem) htmlElem.lang = lang;
          setIsLocaleLoaded(true);
        }
      })

      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  const setCustomLocale = (lang: SupportedLanguage) => {
    switchLocale(lang);
    setLocale(lang);
  };

  const t = (path: string, vars: { [key: string]: string } = {}) => {
    if (Object.keys(dictionary).length == 0) return '';
    try {
      let res = dictionary;
      path.split('.').forEach((key: string) => {
        if (isEntry(res)) {
          res = res[key];
        }
      });
      if (isString(res))
        return res.replaceAll(
          /\$\w+/g,
          (grp) => vars[grp.slice(1)] || grp.slice(1)
        );
      return path;
    } catch (err) {
      return path;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasCookie('locale')) {
      setCookie('locale', locale);
    }
    router.replace('/');

    const selectedLanguage = getCookie('locale');
    if (selectedLanguage == 'de' || selectedLanguage == 'en') {
      switchLocale(selectedLanguage);
    }
  }, []);

  return {
    locale,
    switchLocale,
    t,
    supportedLanguages,
    setCustomLocale,
    isLocaleLoaded,
  };
}
```

And then I call it like this in my
**app.js**:

```
 const {
    locale,
    switchLocale,
    t,
    supportedLanguages,
    setCustomLocale,
    isLocaleLoaded,
  } = useLocale();
```

The API call is also one of the last being made.

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from C:\Repositories\arcneo-website\.env
warn  - Your project has `@next/font` installed as a dependency, please use the built-in `next/font` instead. The `@next/font` package will be removed in Next.js 14. You can migrate by running `npx @next/codemod@latest built-in-next-font .`. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/built-in-next-font

warn - The `@variants` directive has been deprecated in Tailwind CSS v3.0.
warn - Use `@layer utilities` or `@layer components` instead.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#replace-variants-with-layer
event - compiled client and server successfully in 5.4s (1233 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 1071 ms (1143 modules)
wait  - compiling /middleware (client and server)...
event - compiled successfully in 100 ms (62 modules)
request /_next/webpack-hmr
request /_next/webpack-hmr
request /_next/webpack-hmr
request /_next/webpack-hmr
request /_next/static/webpack/c942a8d338922f2a.webpack.hot-update.json
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 846 ms (1234 modules)
request /_next/static/development/_devPagesManifest.json
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1008 ms (1263 modules)
request /
request /index/investFolder.svg
request /_next/static/chunks/components_mainPage_faqSection_tsx.js
request /_next/static/chunks/main.js
request /_next/static/chunks/components_footer_tsx.js
request /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js
request /_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js
request /_next/static/chunks/pages/index.js
request /_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js
request /_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js
request /_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js
request /favicon.ico
request /_next/image
request /_next/static/media/image1Mobile.445f124c.png
request /favicon.ico
request /_next/static/development/_devMiddlewareManifest.json
request /svgs/sign_logo_arcneo_green.svg
request /_next/static/development/_devPagesManifest.json
request /icons/icon_entry.svg
request /icons/icon_maturity.svg
request /icons/icon_return.svg
wait  - compiling /api/locale (client and server)...
event - compiled successfully in 81 ms (101 modules)
request /api/locale
locales
request /api/locale
locales
request /api/locale
locales
request /api/locale
locales
request /api/locale
locales
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 1 ms (101 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 1 ms (101 modules)
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
request /favicon_white.ico
request /_next/image
```

I am thinking either a completely other way to handle localization or change the order of the requests so that /api/locale is one of the first being called.

Thanks for you help in advance